# Zero for indexes

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgresql-11

When I do `select * from pg_stat_user_indexes` on one of the tables in production, 2 indexes are showing zero for all 3 columns `idx_scan`, `idx_tup_read` and `idx_tup_fetch`.
One of the indexes is showing size of 12GB and the other one around 6.5 GB.

Does it mean, this indexes is not used?
Postgres version 11.8

Comment: Yes, please check the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/monitoring-stats.html

Comment: Thanks for the documentation link.